# Using Assumptions to evaluate a complex outer product

Tags: assumptions

*Mathematica* doesn't want to enforce assumptions on an expression. I define a complex outer product for a vector *f*

```
Scalar[a_, b_] := Dot[a, Conjugate[b]]
f = {Cos[a/2], E^(I b) Sin[a/2]};
Outer[Scalar, f, f]
```

If I try to define `$Assumptions` or use `Assuming` to say that `a` and `b` are Real elements, it does not simplify the expression for `Outer`.

Comment: `Simplify[Outer[Scalar[{#}, {#2}] &, f, f],  Assumptions -> Element[{a, b}, Reals]]` or `Assuming[{Element[{a, b}, Reals]}, 
 Simplify[Outer[Scalar[{#}, {#2}] &, f, f]]]` ?

Comment: `$Assumptions` and `Assuming` only help with functions that have an `Assumptions` option. Neither `Dot` nor `Outer` take assumptions so there is nothing done with the assumptions.

Comment: @kglr That worked! Maybe how you defined the scalar product with the extra symbols helped to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Simplify[Outer[Scalar[{#}, {#2}] &, f, f], Assumptions -> Element[{a, b}, Reals]]//TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \cos ^2\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) & \frac{1}{2} e^{-i b} \sin (a) \\
>  \frac{1}{2} e^{i b} \sin (a) & \sin ^2\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

or

```
Assuming[{Element[{a, b}, Reals]}, Simplify[Outer[Scalar[{#}, {#2}] &, f, f]]]//TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \cos ^2\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) & \frac{1}{2} e^{-i b} \sin (a) \\
>  \frac{1}{2} e^{i b} \sin (a) & \sin ^2\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$